# Getting Shell Syntax error operand expected

Tags: shell, syntax, performance-testing

Hi guys I am gettig a syntax error when I run this small Shell script and can't figure it out :

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "begin performance logging" > perflog.log
date +"%T.%4N" >> perflog.log
typeset -i startTime=`date +%s`
typeset -i elapse=20
endTime=$(( elapse + startTime ))
while (('date +%s' < endTime)); do
perf top --sort cpu >> perflog.log
done
```

the error is :

```
line 7: ((: date +%s < 31555764956: syntax error: operand expected ( error token is "%s < 31555764956")
```

Comment: You try to use a bash/zsh construct in a sh-script.

Comment: On some systems `/bin/sh` is a link to `/bin/bash`. Not always. So replace the first line with `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Thanks I managed to fix it  by changing `'date +%s'` by ` `date +%s` `